# Python Django: Pass json from view to javascript in template

Tags: javascript, python, django, list

I am new to django.

From my findings, I tried this way, but didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var data = {{json}}
</script>
```

I am trying to use data table from this website, http://www.datatables.net/manual/data.

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
var temp = '{{campaignList|escapejs}}';    // should be a list, but becomes a string
alert(typeof temp)
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#campaigns').DataTable({
        data: temp,
        columns: [
          { data: 'id' },
          { data: 'name' },
          { data: 'date' },
        ]
      });
} );
</script>
```

When I check the type before passing into datatable, the type becomes string. 
I also tried {{campaignList|escapejs}} without quote, but didn't work.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `var data = {{ campaignList|safe }};` ?

Comment: i did. it didn't work too.

Comment: I had tested before and didn't work. I just test again, and it works. Thanks falsetru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `campaignList` is a json string, pass it to [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to prevent escape:

```
var data = {{ campaignList|safe }};
```